# drupal database import/export issue

Tags: mysql, drupal-7

Am trying to change server of drupal site (drupal-7) . The first phase was to port the database. drupal simply mentions to take a dump and import where needed.

Am using Toad for MYSQL but when exporting to sql file, it misses the value for some blobs datatypes (replaces that data with a string `System.byte[]`).

when exported as csv file, it seems to give some other errors while importing.

kindly assist (step by step if possible). to export and import data via Toad for MYSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have used Heidis SQL and it seemed to work.